# Incomplete media url in nested serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-media

I have a django-rest-api application with models Record, Tag and Weight, where Record and Tag have many-to-many relation through the Weight model:

```py
# models.py
class Tag(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='tag_images', null=True, blank=True)

class Record(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='record_files', null=True, blank=True)

class Weight(models.Model):
    record = models.ForeignKey(
        Record,
        related_name='weights',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    tag = models.ForeignKey(
        Tag,
        related_name='weights',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    value = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('record', 'tag',)
```

Both Record and Tag models have a FileField/ImageField parameter. In my REST API view I would like to display Record detail with its full file url and all related Tags with their full image url. This is how my serializers look like:

```py
# serializers.py
class RecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Record
        fields = ('id', 'file', 'tags')

    def get_tags(self, obj):
        return TagSerializer(Tag.objects.filter(weights__in=obj.weights.all()), many=True).data

class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('id', 'image')
```

The problem is that when I see record detail view its file url is complete but tag image urls are not:

```py
# record detail results
{
    "id": 1,
    "file": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/media/record_files/record00.mp3",
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "image": "/media/tag_images/image04.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "image": "/media/tag_images/image10.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the end I have bypassed the problem by creating a separate tag list view and now the urls are complete even though a haven't changed a bit in my serializers.py.

```py
# record tag list results
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/media/tag_images/image04.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/media/tag_images/image10.jpg"
    }
]
```

I suppose this is a cleaner rest api solution anyway (even though I am pretty sure I will not need record detail and its tags separately). Nevertheless, it still bugs me why the urls are incomplete when the data are part of a nested serializer. Is this how its meant to be or what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you may have found a better solution, but just in case you are still curious: the problem with your initial attempt was that you put the "nested" serializer call inside a `SerializerMethodField`.  The usual way to declare a [nested serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects) is to initialize the serializer when setting the actual field.  In your case it would look something like this:

```
class RecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagSerializer()
```

When you do it this way, the `TagSerializer` can infer context from the parent serializer, and part of that context is the request.  This is then used in `to_representation` in a call to `build_absolute_uri` to generate the full url you were hoping for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have read the usual way to declare nested serializers. Nevertheless, the Tag model is not connected directly over foreign key to the Record model (they relate to each other over Weight model) so I get the "'Record' object has no attribute 'tags'." error and I haven't found a way to pass required data other then SerializerMethodField. Apart from that I am not sure how to access the current record (object saved in the obj variable in my example) other than SerializerMethodField. Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, I misread.  When you said "through the Weight model" I assumed you had a `ManyToMany` relation with a [through model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) (which the weight model looks like).  That's one option.

Comment: If you absolutely don't want to have direct a relation in the db, then the only other "standard" way I know to handle it would be double nesting (include a `WeightSerializer` which nests a `TagSerializer`).  Another hacky option would be to generate a fake `request` and pass it in to the `TagSerializer` in get_tags, but that's a lot more work.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize your serializer like this in your view:

`serialized_store = StoreSerializer(store, context={"request": request})`

[source](https://masnun.com/2015/10/26/django-rest-framework-displaying-full-url-for-imagefield-or-filefield.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need overwrite the method:

```
def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {'request': self.request}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. By passing the context in Serializer, you can get the complete URL:

```
 def get_tags(self, obj):
        return TagSerializer(Tag.objects.filter(weights__in=obj.weights.all()), many=True, context=self.context).data
```